# Boot partition nearly full: how to clear or extend it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition

I got a warning message that my boot partition (`/`) is nearly full. I am running Ubuntu.

Should I clear it or try to extend it ?

To extend, my problem is that the next partition, which is the `/home` is already used.

To clear it, I remove unused kernel, by listing them 
`sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'`  and then removing `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.2.0-45-server`. 
I also cleared apt-cache `apt-get clean`.

Is there other solutions or cleaning to do to win space on the boot partition ?

Thanks for advices

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I think this problem was not caused by unused kernels but just try it and if it doesn't help, you could re-install your OS.